# Way to call methods of multiple objects from the same class using less code

Tags: java, methods

Suppose that I have a code like that:

```
public class Setter {             //Make a class
    public setSomething(int a); {
       variable = a;
    }
}

Setter s1 = new Setter(); //Make objects
Setter s2 = new Setter();
Setter s3 = new Setter();
...
Setter s10 = new Setter();

s1.setSomething(123); //Call methods
s2.setSomething(123);
s3.setSomething(123);
...
s10.setSomething(123);
```

Is there any other way to call those methods without having to type every single one manually?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) or a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, add them to list and then iterate through that list:

```
List<Setter> setters = new ArrayList<Setter>();
setters.add(s1);
//... add more ...

for (Setter s: setters) {
   s.setSomething(123);
}
```